# How to hide/show section levels in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table of contents (`\tableofcontents`) in my document. How can I hide subsections in it? I want that only names of sections are displayed there.

Comment: Write `\subsection*{}` with the asterisk, for a single case, or include `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` in your preamble for anything below `Section` (subsections, subsubsections won't appear). I think this question has certainly come up before...

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` is quicker ;-)

Comment: @Alenanno: Must --- resist--- to answer... this ToC question ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added it while you were posting lol

Comment: By the way, note that the asterisk will make the affected parts unnumbered!

Comment: @Alenanno thanks, than I will  use \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `tocdepth` counter decides to which depth down the entries appear in the `ToC`.

(Code slightly edited, thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1357/jdh for pointing me to a typo!)

Usually, following values hold

- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}` -- only parts
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` -- only parts and chapters
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` -- part,chapters,sections
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` -- part,chapters,sections, subsections
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` -- part,chapters,sections, subsections,subsubsections
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` -- part,chapters,sections, subsections,subsubsections and paragraphs
- `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` -- part,chapters,sections, subsections, subsubsections, paragraphs and subparagraphs.

The `memoir` class adds the ToC depth `-2` for the `\book` structure level at all, being higher leveled than `\part`.

This means, the larger the number for the counter, the greater the number of structuring in the ToC.

The toclevels can be found, for example in `article.cls` (and since `book.cls` loads `article.cls`) looking at the `\@startsection{...}` commands.

If for example, some parts of the structuring should not appear in the ToC at all, there's a trick

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
```

before the 'hidden parts' and later reenable them with

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
```

See [Switching tocdepth in the middle of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395856/switching-tocdepth-in-the-middle-of-a-document) for an example about changing the `tocdepth` in between.

Please do not confuse `tocdepth` with the `secnumdepth` counter!

---

Just for completeness: Both `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth` are counters that aren't defined with`\newcounter`, but have the internal names `\c@tocdepth` and `\c@secnumdepth` in order to allow `\setcounter` etc. usage. You won't find them in the internal counter list and are no members of counter reset lists by default, which would be no of importance anyway.

The value of the `tocdepth` counter controls in the same manner which entries enter the regular bookmarks provided by `hyperref`.

Comment: You are missing {toc} in the trick, in the second line where you reenable the level. (And thanks for this trick!)

Comment: @JDH: Thanks for notifying -- I've corrected the typo.

Comment: How would this work for a specific level only? Like subsections only?

Comment: @JDH Do these settings change the minitoc setting as well?

Comment: @Wallflower I don't know.

Comment: @JDH It does ..