# How to increase the depth of my toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to increase the depth of my table of contents in the following (or a similar) way:

Part I

Chapter 1

A.

1.

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.1.1

B.

2.

2.1

... and so on.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this answer here is pretty exhaustive: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291312/82917.

Comment: You can set `\setcounter{tocdepth}{<number>}`, ranging from {-1} (parts) to {5} (sub-paragraphs). Nesting too deep is frowned upon, but this is how you set the depth of your ToC.

Comment: I find the way of numbering weird. Why are sections 'enumerated' with letters and subsections with numbers again, without usage of the section letter in order to indicate to which section they belong?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, it is. I finally decided to number the sections of each part from the beginning.