# hyperref is not automatically generating bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I am trying to make automatically generate bookmark in my PDF file, but `hyperref` is not doing so. Here is my code. Any idea what am I missing.

```
% nVSDguide.tex
% v4.0 released October 2014

%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{nVSD2e}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\title{How well does?}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    The effect is very easy to construct.   
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
jack for none.
\section{Procedure}
here it is.. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `nVSD2e` document class available online somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: Hi Mico, here is the link for the nVSD2e.cls [https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bq1kyj5ga9zf3f/nVSD2e.cls?dl=0]

Comment: Is the `mcode` package available online?

Comment: Thanks, that works. but if I would like to keep the `nVSD2e.cls`, do you konw how I should `\newcommand` or something so that it woks for my case?

Comment: here is the `mcode` link: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o9ibt15013fipt/mcode.sty?dl=0]

Comment: Yes, now I have shorted the code. if I use `nVSD2e` as `documentclass`, the bookmarking in PDF file works perfectly fine. But If I use `article` as `documentclass`, the bookmarking in PDF file does NOT work.

Comment: Did you mean to write this the other way round, i.e., you get bookmarks if the `article` document class is used but not if the `nVSD2e` document class is used? (At least, that's the result on my system -- TeXlive2017...)

Comment: Exactly, Mico. You are right. But, the problem is, I need to use `nVSD2e` document class while I would, at the same time, like to get the bookmarking in PDF.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I am going to do as you have said. Probably I would also send link to this page, so that they know what I am trying to explain.

Comment: The `nVSD2e` class is very, very, very, very strange. Don't use it.

Comment: For my information : what is a bookmark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `nVSD2e` class is very weird, defining a lot of strange things, even having an own version of `\document`, but the culprit is that `tocdepth` is set to `0` since there is no explicit code like `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` as in `article.cls` so  the default value of `0`is applied, meaning that only `chapters` or `parts` enter the `.toc` or bookmarks, but the `nVSD2e` class does not even provide `\chapter` or `\part` macros.

There is no `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures` etc. command, no `\contentsname` defined.

The whole class looks like glued together without proper understanding of TeX/LaTeX.

In short: Setting `tocdepth` to a value higher than `0`, i.e. `2` or `3` etc. settles this issue, depending on the desired ToC leveling. (See [How to hide/show section levels in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291307/how-to-hide-show-section-levels-in-the-table-of-contents) for more on this topic.)

```
\documentclass{nVSD2e}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\title{How well does?}

\author{I.S.Hould Not Use This Class}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
    The effect is very easy to construct.   
\end{abstract}

See \ref{intro}

\section{Introduction} \label{intro}
jack for none.
\section{Procedure}
here it is.. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christian Hupfer :) It has solved my issue.