# How to hide/show some levels of the Table of Contents in different tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, parts

[image]I am writing a project where I include different table of contents and levels go from Parts to subsubsections. I would like to include a table of contents at the start before all the parts that only shows this level (parts -1) and then a table of contents inside each part that shows chapters to subsubsections of that specific part. I looked at the tips in this question [How to hide/show section levels in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291307/how-to-hide-show-section-levels-in-the-table-of-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1) but could not figure out how to get exactly what I want.
I am writing the parts in different .tex documents and inputing into the main.tex afterwards, I guess this should affect the commands in use. Would it be easier if everything was in the same .tex?

Thank you!

Example:

Title page

General ToC

- part 1
- part 2
- part 3

Part 1
ToC Part 1

- chap 1
  section 1
- chap 2

Part 2
ToC Part 2

- chap 1
  section 1
- chap 2

Comment: Welcome! The question would be easier to answer if you provided which document class you are using, TOC packages etc as it stands its difficult to answer as the answer changes if you are using `memoir` or `book` for example

Comment: How are you getting multiple ToCs? In general there is only one per document. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) which we can compile that shows what you are doing, what you have tried, and what your problem is.

Comment: [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) has a partial lists utility. Check its user manual, sec. 6.4.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for the answers. The type of document is a book. The structure simplified has been posted in the question with a picture. With the first TOC i would like to get a table of contents only with the titles of the parts and inside part 1 the table of contents i want is one with only the sections, subsections, ... of that part. Thanks!