# Changing subsection label in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, labels, books, subsection, labelling

I'm going to apply this: [How to hide/show section levels in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291307/how-to-hide-show-section-levels-in-the-table-of-contents) but I also want to not show the numbering in the subsection label. For example, in the next picture I want the subsection label appear BUT without the numbering.

[image]

Is that possible? The text is in spanish but the idea is the same.
I'm using a `book` as document class. What I want to get is (using enumerate and itemize environments):

[image]

That's what I want in the ToC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% tocsubsecprob.tex  SE 651288
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

% stop \chapter starting a new page
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% print \subsection as requested in the body and the ToC
\newcommand{\mysubsec}[1]{\subsection{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{2em}$\bullet$ #1}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{2em}$\bullet$ First subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{2em}$\bullet$ Another subsection}
\mysubsec{Third subsection}
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please acknowledge.

Comment: It works fantastic and I love it but I'd have to change all the sections commands. Do you know any way to do that but changing directly the ToC and not by creating a new command? My english's still a work in progress, sorry if I'm writing incorrectly some things.

Comment: @Peluche I initially tried to change just the ToC but failed. Perhaps someone else could help.

Comment: @Peluche Surely your text editor can change all the `\subsection` to `\mysubsec`.